# SQL either of two values in a list

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I have a list of values and I want to retrieve all entries after a certain date as long as either of two items can be found in the list of values -

I tried with something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date > ?) AND (item1 OR item2 IN (%s))"
 %(date, qForEach(len(my_list)))


def qForEach(list_length):
    s = "?" 
    for i in range((list_length  - 1)):
        s += ",?"
    return s

cursor.execute(statement, bindings)
```

But apparently SQL thinks I'm asking item1 OR item2 and then whether one of them is IN the list. I've also tried a number of other obvious variations none of which seem to get the desired the result.

Comment: Depends on the data patterns. is item1 null if any other item column populated? I would suggest, in either case, changing that part of the criteria to ((item1 IN (%s)) OR (item2 IN (%s)))

Comment: I tried that - it didn't really work - no neither of them are ever null. Do I have to do %(date, qForEach(my_list), qForEach(my_list)) if I separate the two? And also bindings = my_list  + my_list

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the python side of it, but to double-check, what format is your %s in? It should be 'itemName1','ItemName2', etc....

Comment: yeah I got it. It has to be in the format: [date] + my_list + my_list. Also I think I am loosing efficiency by having the OR run with two different IN statements? Is there not a way to do it together?

Comment: Losing efficiency as compared to what? You need a *correct* query before you can begin optimizing.

Comment: I thought the above comment implied I had a correct query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the two items separately.

And you have to ensure that all parameters (`?`) are passed to the second argument of `execute`:

```py
params = ",".join(["?" for i in range(len(my_list))])
statement = """SELECT * FROM MyTable
 WHERE date > ?
   AND (item1 IN (%s) OR item2 IN (%s))""" % (params, params)
bindings = [my_date] + my_list + my_list
cursor.execute(statement, bindings)
```

You could avoid duplicating the binding values by using [numbered parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

```py
params = ",".join(["?"+str(i+2) for i in range(len(my_list))])
statement = """SELECT * FROM MyTable
 WHERE date > ?
   AND (item1 IN (%s) OR item2 IN (%s))""" % (params, params)
bindings = [my_date] + my_list
cursor.execute(statement, bindings)
```

Comment: Doesn't this become less and less efficient as the table gets larger in proportion to %s (my_list)?

Comment: Less efficient than what?

Comment: Is it not parsing the table twice, once for item1 IN (my_list) and once more for item2 in  (my_list) ? Less efficient than (item1 or item2) IN (my_list), if the former logic is what it is actually doing.

Comment: But `(item1 or item2) IN (my_list)` does not work. If the query is not required to return the correct result, `SELECT 42` would be even more efficient.

Comment: I am aware it does not work, but it would be a more efficient logic - hence my question as to how the equivalent logic could be achieved.

Comment: Not at all. This is the most efficient solution.